# Using storeValue and echo in Katalon Recorder

Tags: echo, katalon-studio, regression-testing, katalon-recorder

I have been automating a web application regression test using Katalon Automation Recorder.

There is a part where I want to use a unique application ID that's generated by the system to search for the application again to verify its existence.

For this, I am trying to use the storeValue command like this:

```
(Command | Target | Value)

storeValue | id=_application_enquiry_portlet_WAR_morcmsportlet_custId | customerID |
```

When I run this, the test log does return this message after that line is run:

```
[info] Store 'AA12345' into 'customerID'
```

But when I try to call the saved value again on a different test case (but the same test suite) in a search engine like this:

```
 echo | ${customerID} | |
```

the value doesn't enter.

For the record, I also tried this:

```
 echo | id=s2id_autogen1_search | ${customerID} |
```

because I felt that, the echo still needed a target specified when entering a saved value. The line turned green which usually means it works, but the value doesn't appear in the search box and the log doesn't show the value being called either.

I am afraid that I could be using the wrong syntax, but I have been following what my research has brought me to believe is right. I am not sure what to do or where I am going wrong.

Comment: Try asking in Katalon [forum](https://forum.katalon.com).

Answer (score 0):

**echo** will output the value of the variable in the **Log**. It can be used for debugging purposes.

Try using the command **type** to enter the value into the search box

```
type | id=s2id_autogen1_search | ${customerID} |
```